# Condición de paro de un For

Tags: python

Tengo un archivo de texto que contiene líneas como las siguientes

```
3,5,1,12,2,1,1,5,4,4,yes
1,11,2,8,4,12,4,9,1,2,no
1,5,1,11,1,12,1,8,2,4,yes
2,3,1,7,1,10,1,9,2,9,no
2,12,3,7,2,6,4,13,2,7,no
```

Estoy intentado pasar ese archivo a  una lista con el código siguiente:

```
datos=[]
with open('archivo.data') as f:
    for linea in f:
        datos.append([int(n) for n in linea.split(",") ])
```

**¿Cómo hacer que solo me convierta a int hasta la penúltima columna?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola lo que puedes hacer es validar que es un numero al generar la lista, por ejemplo asi

```
datos=[]
with open('archivo.data') as f:
    for linea in f:
        lineas = linea.split(',')
        #Con el medtodo isnumeric valida si todos los caracteres del string son numericos
        temp_data = [int(n) for n in lineas if  n.isnumeric()]
        #añadimos al final de la lista el string yes/no y reemplazamo el salto de linea con un espacio
        temp_data.append(lineas[-1].replace('\n',''))
        datos.append(temp_data)
print(datos)
```

En la comprension de listas se puede hacer uso de un if para indicar que valores se almacenan en la lista, con esto validamos que es un numero con el metodo **isnumeric**

```
temp_data = [int(n) for n in lineas if  n.isnumeric()]
```

y luego de eso añadimos al final de la lista el string yes/no y tambien reemplazamos el caracter de salto de linea por un espacio vacio

```
temp_data.append(lineas[-1].replace('\n','')
```

El resultado seria este

```
[[3, 5, 1, 12, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 'yes'], [1, 11, 2, 8, 4, 12, 4, 9, 1, 2, 'no'], [1, 5, 1, 11, 1, 12, 1, 8, 2, 4, 'yes'], [2, 3, 1, 7, 1, 10, 1, 9, 2, 9, 'no'], [2, 12, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 13, 2, 7, 'no']]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta es correcta. En dado caso de que sea float, ¿La validación del if cómo quedaría?

Comment: Hola en caso de que sea float, una manera es que esta:
    [int(n) for n in lineas if  n.replace('.', '').replace('-', '').isnumeric()]
Reemplazo el punto y el guion por si es un negativo y luego valido si todo el resultado es numerico.

Answer (score 1):

Dada una línea leida del archivo y termina con '\n'

```
3,5,1,12,2,1,1,5,4,4,yes\n
```

primero eliminados los *whitespaces* con `strip()` y luego la dividimos en sus componentes con `split(",")`. Esto produce una lista de cadenas, algunas de las cuales representan valores numéricos.

Podemos crear una nueva lista usando compresión de listas, pero en lugar de copiar el elemento tal cual, usamos una expresión condicional que primero revisa si el elemento es numérico (y lo convierte). Si no es numérico, se copia tal cual.

En Python la conversión condicional se puede escribir tradicionalemente así:

```
if x.isnumeric():
    valor = int(x)
else:
    valor = x
```

o en su forma compacta, similar al operador ternario `?:` de C/C++, en una sola línea:

```
valor = int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x
```

con lo cual la solución es:

```
datos = []
with open("archivo.data", "r") as data:
    for linea in data:
        valores = [int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in linea.strip().split(",")]
        datos.append(valores)

print(datos)
```

produce:

```
[[3, 5, 1, 12, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 'yes'], [1, 11, 2, 8, 4, 12, 4, 9, 1, 2, 'no'], [1, 5, 1, 11, 1, 12, 1, 8, 2, 4, 'yes'], [2, 3, 1, 7, 1, 10, 1, 9, 2, 9, 'no'], [2, 12, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 13, 2, 7, 'no']]
```

Si quieres leer decimales, puedes usar `float` en lugar de `int`

**Edición**

Es posible acortar aún más el código. Si bien se acorta y funciona, pierde un poco en legibilidad.

En todo caso, aquí está:

```
datos = []
with open("archivo.data", "r") as data:
    datos = [[int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in linea.strip().split(",")] for linea in data.readlines()]

print(datos)
```

Answer (score 0):

si bien las respuestas que te dieron son válidas, también en otro foro, en este caso en particular, donde solo buscas que el último elemento no sea tomado en cuenta, con tu código y limitando el largo de la lista ya sería suficiente:

```
datos=[]
with open('archivo.data') as f:
    for linea in f:
        datos.append([int(n) for n in linea.split(",")[:-1]])
```

donde lo único agrtegado es [:-1] que es una forma de tomar una parte de la lista(slice), en este caso desde el inicio hasta el el final menos 1